# show that S is a connected manifold.

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ := {($x$, $a_3$, $a_2$, $a_1$, $a_0$) $\in \mathbb{R}^5$ | $x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$ }

how to show that S is a connected manifold?
I don't know how to choose continuous path through the manifold.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that this is a manifold?

Answer (score 2):

Since the set $S$ can be realized as graph of the smooth function
$$\phi:\quad{\mathbb R}^4\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (x,a_3,a_2,a_1)\mapsto a_0=-(x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x),$$
it follows that $S$ is a $4$-dimensional submanifold of ${\mathbb R}^5$. Furthermore any point ${\bf x}=(x, a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0)\in S$ can be reached from the point ${\bf 0}\in S$ along the path
$$\gamma_{\bf x}:\quad \lambda\mapsto(\lambda x, \lambda a_3,\lambda^2 a_2,\lambda^3 a_1,\lambda^4 a_0)\qquad(0\leq\lambda\leq 1)$$
lying in $S$.